# Unable to install elasticsearch-head in Windows 7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Unable to install elasticsearch-head in Windows 7. Getting the following error in command prompt.

```
elasticsearch-2.4.0\bin>plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head
Installing mobz/elasticsearch-head...
ing https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip ...
OR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

How to fix?

[update]

```
C:\elasticsearch-2.4.0\bin>plugin.bat install mobz/elasticsearch-head --verbose
-> Installing mobz/elasticsearch-head...
Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

Comment: `use --verbose to get detailed information` can you try that and update your question with that additional info?

Comment: Is this the right way to use --verbose? plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head --verbose

Comment: Yes, try it out, what do you get?

Comment: I have updated the message

Comment: can you access that link from the browser?

Comment: In addition try to run CMD as administrator

Comment: Yep, that's either a networking issue or a privilege one.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat tried CMD as admin but no luck. Yes I'm able to access elasticsearch head in browser after enabling the CORS.

Answer (score 0):

**For ElasticSearch => 5.0
Running as a plugin of Elasticsearch is now deprecated for security problems.**

**1 . Enable CORS in elasticsearch**

config/elasticsearch.yml:

http.cors.enabled : true

http.cors.allow-origin : "*"

http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length

**2. you have to run it in another server, like this for example:**

(you will need npm => 6)

go to: [github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head.git](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head)
**donwload it**

> cd elasticsearch-head
>
> npm install
>
> npm run start
>
> open http://localhost:9100/

it worked for me.